# Exist a sample or template database for BI about sales/inventory?

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, snowflake-schema

I will start a reporting tool for some local ERPs about sales, invoices, orders, customers, inventory, etc.

I wonder if exist a sample schema appropriated for this case (in star or snowflake form) so I can have a solid foundation.

I have understanding about basic BI desing, but taking in account this is a common problem, I wonder if exist a starting solution. Obviously, I will need to change some things to fit my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one of Ralph Kimball's books, particularly the 2nd one (I lent it to someone who never returned it, so I can't give you details), take a look at it. I recall that a Sales data model is one of the more prominent ones that he discusses.

Also, look at this [SQL Server 2000 sample datamart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb187300%28SQL.80%29.aspx). Inmon, one of the publishers, co-authored Kimball's books and is also a noted expert in the field. I am not sure if there is an updated version for SQL Server 2008, but this should still be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQL Server 2008, you can find the Analysis Services Solution (called Adventure Works 2008) in this location:(assuming you have installed SQL 2008 in C Drive)

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Samples\AdventureWorks 2008 Analysis Services Project